# Why can't I find a reverse for 'search' with no arguments. 1 pattern attempted: ['blog/search/(?P<search_word>[^/]+)/\\Z' Would this cause this error?

Tags: django

I'm creating a search function and I want to put a search_word value in the URL, but I'm getting this error, how can I fix it?

```
views.py
class Search(View):
    def get(self, request, search_word):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_word) | Q(category__icontains=search_word))
        context = {
            'posts': posts,
            'search_word': search_word
        }
        return render(request, 'blog/post_search.html', context)
```

```
urls.py 
path('search/<str:search_word>/', views.Search.as_view(), name='search'),
```

```
list.html
<form action="{% url 'blog:search' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="search_word" placeholder="검색어를 입력하세요">
            <button type="submit">검색</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you called wrong url.

cuz 'search' path url contains 'search_word' but, you are didn't pass with param. see this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)